# loop through laravel object and read data and assign to a another variable

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel, laravel-5

i want to read laravel  object and assign it in to a another variable 
[image]

[image]

[image]

i want to read those **markets[]** and **products[]** and assign to a another variable please some one help

```
{
   "1006032":{
      "id":1006032,
      "name":"Germany Regionalliga North East 22",
      "start_date":"2020-02-20 18:00:00",
      "icon":null,
      "display_flag":1,
      "base_competition_id":1000028,
      "events":[
         {
            "id":1051919,
            "name":"Hertha Berlin II & ZFC Meuselwitz",
            "display_flag":1,
            "start_date":"2020-02-20 18:00:00",
            "competition_id":1006032,
            "market_count":1,
            "dst_uri":"",
            "teams":[
               {
                  "id":3106,
                  "name":"Hertha Berlin II",
                  "icon":null,
                  "display_flag":0,
                  "position":"home",
                  "requested_at":15821738127576
               },
               {
                  "id":3107,
                  "name":"ZFC Meuselwitz",
                  "icon":null,
                  "display_flag":0,
                  "position":"away",
                  "requested_at":15821738127578
               }
            ],
            "markets":[
               {
                  "id":1051560,
                  "name":"Match Winner",
                  "line":0,
                  "market_status":"O",
                  "display_flag":1,
                  "market_type_id":1000022,
                  "event_id":1051919,
                  "note":"",
                  "boost_available":false,
                  "selections":[
                     {
                        "id":455957,
                        "name":"Home",
                        "line":0,
                        "price":5,
                        "won":false,
                        "display_flag":1,
                        "selection_status_id":1,
                        "requested_at":15821738127597
                     },
                     {
                        "id":455958,
                        "name":"Draw",
                        "line":0,
                        "price":8,
                        "won":false,
                        "display_flag":1,
                        "selection_status_id":1,
                        "requested_at":15821738127601
                     },
                     {
                        "id":455959,
                        "name":"Away",
                        "line":0,
                        "price":4,
                        "won":false,
                        "display_flag":1,
                        "selection_status_id":1,
                        "requested_at":15821738127604
                     }
                  ],
                  "markettypegroup":{
                     "id":1,
                     "name":"More Markets",
                     "description":"Markets Types that have not been grouped",
                     "display_flag":1,
                     "icon":null,
                     "requested_at":15821738127606
                  },
                  "requested_at":15821738127606
               }
            ],
            "products":[
               {
                  "product_id":10,
                  "bet_type":null,
                  "product_code":"TBF",
                  "product_name":"TopBetta Fixed",
                  "fixed":true,
                  "available":true,
                  "product_image":null,
                  "ribbon_image":null,
                  "has_pool":false,
                  "product_description":"Guarantees to pay at least the best of the 3 TAB dividends",
                  "product_note":null,
                  "product_tooltip":null,
                  "background_colour":null,
                  "multi_available":false,
                  "ordinal":0,
                  "margin":0,
                  "product_type":"standard",
                  "price_id":0,
                  "pool_total":0,
                  "first_leg":null,
                  "requested_at":15821738127616
               }
            ],
            "requested_at":15821738127616
         }
      ],
      "base_competition":{
         "id":1000028,
         "name":"Germany Regionalliga North East",
         "icon":null,
         "display_flag":1,
         "sport_id":19,
         "order":0,
         "sport":{
            "id":19,
            "name":"Soccer",
            "icon":null,
            "display_flag":1,
            "order":0,
            "requested_at":15821738127621
         },
         "requested_at":15821738127621
      },
      "requested_at":15821738127621
   },
   "1005312":{
      "id":1005312,
      "name":"WNCAAB ",
      "start_date":"1970-01-01 00:00:00",
      "icon":null,
      "display_flag":1,
      "base_competition_id":1000215,
      "events":[
         {
            "id":1051924,
            "name":"Fordham Women & Davidson Women",
            "display_flag":1,
            "start_date":"2020-02-23 00:00:00",
            "competition_id":1005312,
            "market_count":1,
            "dst_uri":"",
            "teams":[
               {
                  "id":810,
                  "name":"Fordham Women",
                  "icon":null,
                  "display_flag":0,
                  "position":"home",
                  "requested_at":15821738127629
               },
               {
                  "id":2610,
                  "name":"Davidson Women",
                  "icon":null,
                  "display_flag":0,
                  "position":"away",
                  "requested_at":15821738127631
               }
            ],
            "markets":[
               {
                  "id":1051565,
                  "name":"Match Winner",
                  "line":0,
                  "market_status":"O",
                  "display_flag":1,
                  "market_type_id":1000022,
                  "event_id":1051924,
                  "note":"",
                  "boost_available":false,
                  "selections":[
                     {
                        "id":455973,
                        "name":"Draw",
                        "line":0,
                        "price":2,
                        "won":false,
                        "display_flag":1,
                        "selection_status_id":1,
                        "requested_at":15821738127649
                     },
                     {
                        "id":455974,
                        "name":"Away",
                        "line":0,
                        "price":3,
                        "won":false,
                        "display_flag":1,
                        "selection_status_id":1,
                        "requested_at":15821738127652
                     }
                  ],
                  "markettypegroup":{
                     "id":1,
                     "name":"More Markets",
                     "description":"Markets Types that have not been grouped",
                     "display_flag":1,
                     "icon":null,
                     "requested_at":15821738127654
                  },
                  "requested_at":15821738127654
               }
            ],
            "products":[
               {
                  "product_id":10,
                  "bet_type":null,
                  "product_code":"TBF",
                  "product_name":"TopBetta Fixed",
                  "fixed":true,
                  "available":true,
                  "product_image":null,
                  "ribbon_image":null,
                  "has_pool":false,
                  "product_description":"Guarantees to pay at least the best of the 3 TAB dividends",
                  "product_note":null,
                  "product_tooltip":null,
                  "background_colour":null,
                  "multi_available":false,
                  "ordinal":0,
                  "margin":0,
                  "product_type":"standard",
                  "price_id":0,
                  "pool_total":0,
                  "first_leg":null,
                  "requested_at":15821738127662
               }
            ],
            "requested_at":15821738127662
         },
         {
            "id":1051923,
            "name":"NC State Women & Louisville Women",
            "display_flag":1,
            "start_date":"2020-02-23 01:00:00",
            "competition_id":1005312,
            "market_count":1,
            "dst_uri":"",
            "teams":[
               {
                  "id":3114,
                  "name":"NC State Women",
                  "icon":null,
                  "display_flag":0,
                  "position":"home",
                  "requested_at":15821738127668
               },
               {
                  "id":3115,
                  "name":"Louisville Women",
                  "icon":null,
                  "display_flag":0,
                  "position":"away",
                  "requested_at":15821738127670
               }
            ],
            "markets":[
               {
                  "id":1051564,
                  "name":"Match Winner",
                  "line":0,
                  "market_status":"O",
                  "display_flag":1,
                  "market_type_id":1000022,
                  "event_id":1051923,
                  "note":"",
                  "boost_available":false,
                  "selections":[
                     {
                        "id":455970,
                        "name":"Draw",
                        "line":0,
                        "price":2,
                        "won":false,
                        "display_flag":1,
                        "selection_status_id":1,
                        "requested_at":15821738127688
                     },
                     {
                        "id":455971,
                        "name":"Away",
                        "line":0,
                        "price":3,
                        "won":false,
                        "display_flag":1,
                        "selection_status_id":1,
                        "requested_at":15821738127691
                     }
                  ],
                  "markettypegroup":{
                     "id":1,
                     "name":"More Markets",
                     "description":"Markets Types that have not been grouped",
                     "display_flag":1,
                     "icon":null,
                     "requested_at":15821738127693
                  },
                  "requested_at":15821738127693
               }
            ],
            "products":[
               {
                  "product_id":10,
                  "bet_type":null,
                  "product_code":"TBF",
                  "product_name":"TopBetta Fixed",
                  "fixed":true,
                  "available":true,
                  "product_image":null,
                  "ribbon_image":null,
                  "has_pool":false,
                  "product_description":"Guarantees to pay at least the best of the 3 TAB dividends",
                  "product_note":null,
                  "product_tooltip":null,
                  "background_colour":null,
                  "multi_available":false,
                  "ordinal":0,
                  "margin":0,
                  "product_type":"standard",
                  "price_id":0,
                  "pool_total":0,
                  "first_leg":null,
                  "requested_at":15821738127701
               }
            ],
            "requested_at":15821738127701
         }
      ],
      "base_competition":{
         "id":1000215,
         "name":"WNCAAB",
         "icon":null,
         "display_flag":1,
         "sport_id":13,
         "order":0,
         "sport":{
            "id":13,
            "name":"Basketball",
            "icon":null,
            "display_flag":1,
            "order":0,
            "requested_at":15821738127706
         },
         "requested_at":15821738127706
      },
      "requested_at":15821738127706
   },
   "1006033":{
      "id":1006033,
      "name":"Iran Pro League 20",
      "start_date":"2020-02-23 12:00:00",
      "icon":null,
      "display_flag":null,
      "base_competition_id":1000161,
      "events":[
         {
            "id":1051925,
            "name":"Peykan & Foolad Khuzestan",
            "display_flag":1,
            "start_date":"2020-02-23 12:00:00",
            "competition_id":1006033,
            "market_count":1,
            "dst_uri":"",
            "teams":[
               {
                  "id":3116,
                  "name":"Peykan",
                  "icon":null,
                  "display_flag":0,
                  "position":"home",
                  "requested_at":15821738127713
               },
               {
                  "id":696,
                  "name":"Foolad Khuzestan",
                  "icon":null,
                  "display_flag":0,
                  "position":"away",
                  "requested_at":15821738127716
               }
            ],
            "markets":[
               {
                  "id":1051566,
                  "name":"Match Winner",
                  "line":0,
                  "market_status":"O",
                  "display_flag":1,
                  "market_type_id":1000022,
                  "event_id":1051925,
                  "note":"",
                  "boost_available":false,
                  "selections":[
                     {
                        "id":455976,
                        "name":"Draw",
                        "line":0,
                        "price":2,
                        "won":false,
                        "display_flag":1,
                        "selection_status_id":1,
                        "requested_at":15821738127733
                     },
                     {
                        "id":455977,
                        "name":"Away",
                        "line":0,
                        "price":3,
                        "won":false,
                        "display_flag":1,
                        "selection_status_id":1,
                        "requested_at":15821738127736
                     }
                  ],
                  "markettypegroup":{
                     "id":1,
                     "name":"More Markets",
                     "description":"Markets Types that have not been grouped",
                     "display_flag":1,
                     "icon":null,
                     "requested_at":15821738127739
                  },
                  "requested_at":15821738127739
               }
            ],
            "products":[
               {
                  "product_id":10,
                  "bet_type":null,
                  "product_code":"TBF",
                  "product_name":"TopBetta Fixed",
                  "fixed":true,
                  "available":true,
                  "product_image":null,
                  "ribbon_image":null,
                  "has_pool":false,
                  "product_description":"Guarantees to pay at least the best of the 3 TAB dividends",
                  "product_note":null,
                  "product_tooltip":null,
                  "background_colour":null,
                  "multi_available":false,
                  "ordinal":0,
                  "margin":0,
                  "product_type":"standard",
                  "price_id":0,
                  "pool_total":0,
                  "first_leg":null,
                  "requested_at":15821738127747
               }
            ],
            "requested_at":15821738127747
         }
      ],
      "base_competition":{
         "id":1000161,
         "name":"Iran Pro League",
         "icon":null,
         "display_flag":"1",
         "sport_id":19,
         "order":0,
         "sport":{
            "id":19,
            "name":"Soccer",
            "icon":null,
            "display_flag":1,
            "order":0,
            "requested_at":15821738127751
         },
         "requested_at":15821738127751
      },
      "requested_at":15821738127751
   }
}
```

Comment: use this http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/ and check your data properly then get data by` key` `$data['key']['key2']....['markets']`

Comment: can you explane with a example please

Comment: can you send your data as code format without picture then i can

Comment: i updated json  please help

Comment: The question doesn't appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: what i have tried is i type cast object to array  and tried to loop thought   $competitions = $competitionService->getCompetitionsByN2JEventResourcesGrs($nextToJump->slice(0, array_get($config, 'next_to_jump_events')));
       
       $arrayCom = (array) $competitions;
       
      foreach($arrayCom as $item) {
     Log::info($item['id']);

      }

Comment: but it say's   Undefined index: id

Answer (score 0):

try this you

```
$markets = []; $products = [];
foreach($yourdata as $key => $data){

if(isset($data['events'][0]['markets']))
 $markets[$key][] = $data['events'][0]['markets'];

 //if you want get only one data insight markets in 0 
 // then use $markets[$key][] = $data['events'][0]['markets'][0];
 if(isset($data['events'][0]['products']))
 $products[$key][] = $data['events'][0]['products'];

 // $products[$key][] = $data['events'][0]['products'][0];

}
```

if you have multiple events in single object use like this

```
 foreach($yourdata as $key => $data){

          if(isset($data['events']))
         foreach($data['events'] as $event){
          if(isset($data['markets']))
          $markets[$key][] = $event['markets'];
          if(isset($data['products']))
          $products[$key][] = $event['products'];
         }

        }

        dd($markets,$products);
```

Comment: cant' read  $data['events']  it's say's Undefined index: events

Comment: put `dd($data)` insight foreach and check you get `events` key and  put `isset()` check my answer

Comment: dd inside for each printing but i cat access events in side it

Comment: where did you get this data ? what is format ? if data format is json ? then convert to array `json_decode($jsondata)` then do foreach because i used your data it wokrs fine

Comment: for your second example there is no error but  when i dd market array is empty

Comment: this is my function

Comment: $nextToJump = $cachedEventResourceService->nextToJump();
       $markets=array();
       
       $config = $configurationRepository->getConfigByName('sports_settings', true);
       $competitions = $competitionService->getCompetitionsByN2JEventResourcesGrs($nextToJump->slice(0, array_get($config, 'next_to_jump_events')));
       
       $arrayCom = (array) $competitions;

Comment: i receive collection object data to that $competitions  variable   $competitions variable you see in pictures and json i updated  then i type cast it to a array  then trying to read data

Comment: $competitions = $competitionService->getCompetitionsByN2JEventResourcesGrs($nextToJump->slice(0, array_get($config, 'next_to_jump_events')));
       
       $arrayCom = (array) $competitions;
       
$markets = []; $products = [];

foreach($arrayCom as $key => $data){

          if(isset($data['events']))
         foreach($data['events'] as $event){
          if(isset($data['markets']))
          $markets[$key][] = $event['markets'];
          if(isset($data['products']))
          $products[$key][] = $event['products'];
         }

        }